# requisição do banco com php não retorna um array multidimensional

Tags: php, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou com problema para usar o array do php, quando tento mudar para $row[0][0] o que me retorna é só a primeira letra. Meu banco de dados é multidimensional, mas na requisição só resulta em um array com a primeira linha. Como posso fazer uma requisição de todo o banco?

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `missao`";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row[0];
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

*"Meu banco de dados é multidimensional"* o que quer dizer com isso? que banco de dados "multimensional" é esse?

Acho que está confundindo o conceito do banco de dados com o retorno ser "multidimensioal"

Aqui está fazendo mal uso do `mysqli`, `$row`, até como o nome sugere, é uma linha da tabela, e o índice passado entre `[]` é a coluna, por exemplo zero é "ID" e um é "NOME", quando faz `$row[0]` retorna a primeira coluna e `$row[0][0]` o primeiro caractere da primeira coluna, como no seu exemplo.

Não tem um array "[linha][coluna]" com `mysqli_fetch_array`, para fazer o que deseja use [`mysqli_fetch_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)

Assim é possível fazer `$row[0][0]`.

Algumas observações:

- evite usar o `SELECT *`, isso vai fazer com que nunca saiba qual é a coluna 0,1 etc, se a tabela mudar o resultado vai mudar, prefira passar explicitamente os nomes dos campos:
- usar o `mysqli_fetch_all` para ler o par "[linha][coluna]" vai fazer retornar todos os dados de uma vez, o que dependendo do tamanho da tabela pode ser um problema... prefira no lugar disso, ler cada linha dentro de um bloco `foreach`, assim trata cada linha idividualmente
- por fim, na sequência do comentário aterior, se ler todo o array de uma vez, vai precisar saber onde ele termina (total de linhas), ao passo que se usar um `foreach` isso não será necessário.

Veja o exemplo no link acima com `foreach`:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name, CountryCode FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 3");

$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $row["Name"], $row["CountryCode"]);
}
```

Comment: Agradeço muito a ajuda, tenho pouca experiência com php e backend no geral por isso o erro nos conceitos básicos kk. Consegui resolver o problema, levei em consideração também as observações e já consertei no meu código.

Comment: por nada, parece que "as outras pessoas" não gostaram da resposta não sei porque, mas é assim mesmo